# Clipping VRT with mask layer results in too large VRT

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, clip

i have created with QGIS a VRT holding ~400 raster tiles,  the totaling size of all rasters held in this VRT is around 90GB, the file size of the VRT is 1.9MB. I now want to clip this VRT with a mask layer using the "Clip raster by mask layer" native plugin. As a result i want an VRT again. The operation succeeds with no error message - but the resulting VRT has a file size of 34MB now and it does not load (for ~14h) in QGIS when want to add it to the map canvas. How can i create a VRT with the clipped extent? Is there another, more performant way to achieve this?

Comment: "it does not load in QGIS", do you get an error message or what?

Comment: no, i was waiting for overnight for it to load while QGIS beeing frozen

Comment: Maybe this answer could help here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294591/very-large-vrt-file-generated-by-gdal-after-cutline/294681?noredirect=1#comment473080_294681